# Entity Framework inserts only one record

Tags: c#, oracle, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I'm saving a record in my database by passing 3 parameters, the number parameter is passed to pick the number of records from one table to another table. However the loop written inserts only 1 record instead of the number parameter passed.

I'm using the the `Take()` method in Entity Framework to pick the records. It inserts only the last records in the loop

```
public async Task<bool> Save(string company, int number, string registrationNumber)
{
    using (var trans = _dbContext.Database.BeginTransaction())
    {
        var db = new SibaCiidDbContext();
        var dbSet = _dbContext.Set<IntermediaryAssignment>();

        // pick number of records 
        var data = await (from s in db.StickerDistributions
                          where s.Dispatched == false &&  
                                s.CompanyCode == company
                          select s).Take(number).ToListAsync();

        var intermediary = (await _repo.FindBy(s => s.RegistrationNumber  == registrationNumber && 
                                                    s.Status == EntityStatus.Active)).FirstOrDefault();

        var entity = new IntermediaryAssignment();

        foreach (var sticker in data)
        {
            entity.CompanyCode = sticker.CompanyCode;
            entity.StickerCode = sticker.StickerCode;
            entity.RegistrationNumber = intermediary.RegistrationNumber;
            entity.Status = EntityStatus.Active;
            entity.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
            entity.Dispatched = false;
            entity.IntermediaryType = intermediary.IntermediaryType;

            dbSet.Add(entity);
        }

        trans.Commit();

        return  await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync() > 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: How many records do you get into the Data object?

Comment: If I pass 3 as the number,i get 3 in the data object but it inserts only the last item in the object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating one entity, and then updating it 3 times.  You need to create a new entity for each new record.

Move the `new IntermediaryAssignment()` inside the loop.

```
     foreach (var sticker in data)
     {
            var entity = new IntermediaryAssignment();


            entity.CompanyCode = sticker.CompanyCode;
            entity.StickerCode = sticker.StickerCode;
            entity.RegistrationNumber = intermediary.RegistrationNumber;
            entity.Status = EntityStatus.Active;
            entity.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
            entity.Dispatched = false;
            entity.IntermediaryType = intermediary.IntermediaryType;


            dbSet.Add(entity);

        }
```